# how to add condition to not execute code for given user

Tags: abap

I want to pass some abap code without executing according to sap user.

Here an example:

```
if userName is John Then 
  pass this code block without executing...
endif
```

Is it possible?

Is it possible to debug it so that when we add `break <user_name>`, the debug runs only for that user?

Comment: Sure this is possible. Inspect the "sy" structure during runtime. There You will find plenty information. also Username. But this mostly is a bad approach. AuthorityCheck is sap-standard to execute special programms/code-flows depending on user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you could if it is absolutely necessary . The system stores the user alias executing the program under the variable `sy-uname` and you can use this to do your condition check . But I wouldn't recommend this approach as it is not immediately visible why a certain block of code is being executed for some users and is bypassed for others. This would/should never pass a stringent quality check during code analysis .

Comment: Thanks for reply. Part of the program is working wrong and test user wanted to this part of code pass for him until developer recover the code. This solution is for temporal.

Comment: We use this approach during development (due to the lack of 'check in/check out' in SAP, do not want to disrupt other teams), but remove it when transporting to test. It is not ideal, but serves a purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, the technical solution would be:

```
IF sy-uname NE 'JOHN'.
 * Code that is not executed for SAP user 'JOHN'
ENDIF.
```